# How can I insert activity diagram image to an use case in Enterprise architect?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, activity-diagram, use-case-diagram

I have been trying to link use case with an activity diagram (To get detailed outline of process). I know there is a method to do such thing. I have seen such example. But I don't know how to introduce it in my diagram.

I tried various methods like right clicking on the use case and experimenting all the options, but it was of no use. Can anyone explain me the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

There might be quicker options, but the way that will definitely work is simply to create an activity *and* an activity diagram contained by it and then drag it in the project browser and drop it in the use case.

You could also create a scenario in the use case properties dialog. Then there is a button to create a diagram from this scenario. Be sure to select the option that creates actions from the scenario steps. Some of the options create a malformed model.